# Define a theme for Gridview with BoundFields in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, themes, templatefield, boundfield

I defined a theme for Gridview in ASP .NET Theme folder. It is as follows.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-responsive-md table-bordered table-sm table-striped" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="bg-primary text-center small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="text-center small"  />
```

Now the problem is this theme is getting applied to only Grids with ItemTemplates and TemplateFields and not to the ones with BoundFields, how do I generalise the theme and make it applicable to all grids.

Comment: That should not make a difference, the results of Bound or Template is the same: rows and columns in html.

Comment: I checked html, class is not getting applied to bound field rows, whereas they are getting applied to templatefield rows